# Pass arguments to a function within a function within a function

Tags: interpolation, arguments

I want to perform an integration of `f[w,t,kx,ky]` over `t` for several different functions `f`. The `f` depend on a time `t`, is `w`-periodic in it and also depends on two factors `kx` and `ky`. The function is very complicated. So I decided to integrate it for fixed `kx` and `ky` and then interpolate between those.

I have several `w` for which I want to do this individually. In the end, I want a, `kx`- and `ky`-dependent function for each of these (depending on the inserted function `f`).

The concept of my code is the following:

```
MyInterpolatedIntegration[f_, w_, kLimit_, kSteps_, kx_, ky_] :=
  MyInterpolation[MyIntegration[f[#1, #2, #3?, #4?]&, w], kLimit, kSteps][kx, ky]

MyIntegration[function_, w_] := 
  Integrate[Exp[(*something*)] function[w, t], {t, 0, 2 Pi/w}]

MyInterpolation[function_, kLimit_, kSteps_] := 
  MyInterpolation[function, kLimit, kSteps] =
    Interpolation[
      Flatten[
        Table[
          {{κx, κy}, function[κx, κy]},
          {κx, -kLimit, kLimit, 2 kLimit/kSteps},
          {κy, -kLimit, kLimit, 2 kLimit/kSteps}],
        1]]
(* -kLimit to +kLimit with kSteps intermediate steps for both kx and ky *)
```

I want to pass `f[#1, #2, #3, #4]` into `MyInterpolation`, which again should pass `f[#1, #2, kx, ky]` (with fixed `kx` and `ky`) to `MyIntegration`, which should then perform the integral of `f[w, t, kx, ky]` over `t` (for fixed `kx, ky, w`).

My problem now is that I don't know how to control that `#1` becomes `w`, `#2` becomes `t` and `#3` and `#4` become `kx` and `ky` (therefore the ?-marks in my code). I can only manage to control the first insertion of arguments. How do you pass a function with free parameters after already inserting some?

(The actual problem is a little more involved and contains functions like `Eigensystem`. For the sake of readability, I've tried to narrow the problem down to the smallest reasonable problem.)

**Edit:**

(I have also fixed an error in my definition of `MyInterpolatedIntegration`)

According to request, let me provide an example of what my functions should do. At first let's say `f` and `MyIntegration` do the following`:

```
f[w_, t_, kx_, ky_]:= (1+Sin[w*t])*kx*ky
MyIntegration[function_, w_] :=
    Integrate[Exp[I*w*t] function[w, t], {t, 0, 2 Pi/w}]
```

Then I can perform an integration the following way:

```
In[1]:= MyIntegration[f[#1, #2, 1, 1] &, 1]
Out[1]= I Pi
```

for `w=1` and `kx = ky = 1`.

Now I want a similar call for the `MyInterpolationFunction` like

```
In[2]:= MyInterpolation[f[2Pi/3, 0, #1, #2]&, 4, 10]
Out[2]= InterpolatingFunction[(*something*)
```

Here I used the fixed `w = 2Pi/3`, `t = 0` and have an interpolation for `kx` and `ky` both running from -4 to 4 with 10 steps respectively, i.e. the interpolation function will have 100 points to interpolate.

What I'm looking for now, is a function `MyInterpolatedIntegration` which does both the integration depending on `w` and the interpolation for `kx` and `ky`. I want to call this function in a way similar to

```
In[3]:= MyInterpolatedIntegration[f[#1, #2, #3, #4]&, 4, 10, 2Pi/3, 1, 2]
Out[3]= 2 (* I think; maybe I made a mistake here *)]
```

i.e. I want a function that gives me interpolated value for the integral of `f` evaluated at the corresponding entries (here `w = 2Pi/3`, `kx=1`, `ky=2` where the interpolation goes from `kx,ky = -4` to `kx,ky = 4` with 10 respective intermediate steps).

My problem is that I can't simply call `f[#1, #2, #3, #4]&` as an argument. Instead, I need to tell the function in a different manner when every respective parameter will be inserted.

Comment: I think it would be much easier to understand what you are asking if you added example code showing your three defined function in action (i.e., with some actual values) and giving the expected results.

Comment: I have tried to provide a good example, and I have also fixed an error in my previous definitions. I hope that's enough to understand well what I mean. If there are further questions, I will answer them tomorrow, but now I have to leave. Thank you so far for your comment.

Comment: `MyIntegration` retuns a scalar for a symbol assigned a value, `w = 4` or a function of one variable for an unassigned symbol, `w`.  You are passing the former so what are to expecting to interpolate from a single scalar variable?

Comment: At most `MyIntegration` will be a scalar or a function of one variable.  However, `MyInterpolation` is expecting a function of two variables. So there are some issues in your concepts that need to be clarified.

Comment: I want to integrate `f` which depends on `w`, `t`, `kx` and `ky` over `t`, such that the resulting scalar depends on `w`, `kx` and `ky`. I will do this for fixed values of `w`. Thus, the scalar corresponding for a specific `w` will depend on `kx` and `ky`, respectively. This dependence on `kx` and `ky` I want to interpolate. (Please note that the integration is only a placeholder. What I actually want to do with `f` is much more complicated.) The problem is that I want to do the integration with two parameters of `f` while I want to do the interpolation with the other two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having issues because you are assigning values to your symbols too early in the process; namely the integration.

`MyIntegration` retuns a scalar for a symbol assigned a value, `w = 4` or a function of one variable for an unassigned symbol, `w`. You are passing the former so what are to expecting to interpolate from a single scalar variable? At most `MyIntegration` will be a scalar or a function of one variable. However, `MyInterpolation` is expecting a function of two variables.

How to fix this? `Integrate` with respect to both remaining variables so that you have a function of 2 variables as a result. You can use `Evaluate` to assist as it will force the evaluation inside of `Function` and allow you to use the named variables as inputs to the resulting pure function.

The definitions become:

```
ClearAll[MyIntegration]
MyIntegration[function_, w_Symbol, t_Symbol] :=
 Integrate[Exp[I*w*t] function[w, t], w, t]
```

`MyInterpolation` is as in OP.

```
ClearAll[MyInterpolatedIntegration];
MyInterpolatedIntegration[f_, w_Symbol, t_Symbol, kLimit_, kSteps_, kx_, ky_] :=
 MyInterpolation[
  Function[{w, t},
   Evaluate[MyIntegration[f[#1, #2, kx, ky] &, w, t]]
   ],
  kLimit, kSteps]
```

`w` and `t` will syntax highlight red as a warning as in most cases you do not want to reuse the function variables within an inner function in this way but it is okay in this particular corner case.

and `f` as in OP

```
f[w_, t_, kx_, ky_] := (1 + Sin[w*t])*kx*ky
```

Then

```
ClearAll[h, g]
MyInterpolatedIntegration[f, h, g, 10, 2 Pi/3, 1, 2]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ContourPlot[#@if[x, y], 
   {x, Sequence @@ First@if["Domain"]}, 
   {y, Sequence @@ Last@if["Domain"]}, 
   PlotLabel -> #] & /@ {Re, Im}
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Actually, your suggestion doesn't solve my problem the way I intended (I wanted to interpolate in `kx` and `ky`). However, it is the correct way of doing it. If I define `MyInterpolatedIntegration[w_, kx_, ky_]:= (MyInterpolation[Function[{KX, KY}, MyIntegration[f[#1, #2, KX, KY]&, 2 Pi/3]][#1,#2]&, 4, 10])[kx, ky]`, it works (with the other functions defined like in my original post). What I needed was a way to get these additional `#1` and `#2`, and `Function` did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue) instead. For your example:

```
pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {g'[t] == Exp[I w t] (1+Sin[w t]) kx ky, g[0]==0},
    g[2Pi/w],
    {t, 0, 2Pi/w},
    {w, kx, ky}
];
```

Then for `w=1, kx=1, ky=1`:

```
pf[1, 1, 1]
```

> -2.65328*10^-8 + 3.14159 I

And, for `w=2Pi/3, kx=1, ky=2`:

```
pf[2Pi/3, 1, 2]
```

> -2.53459*10^-8 + 3. I

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, this seems to only work for an integration. I used `MyIntegration` as a placeholder. The actual function I have is much more involved. (It uses the integration only as part of a Fourier decomposition to create a large matrix out of the Fourer coefficients to then get the eigensystem of this matrix and generate a function out of them.) So this, unfortunately, won't solve my actual problem. But your suggestion indeed solves the particular problem I presented.

Answer (score 0):

I am now using a workaround:

```
MyInterpolatedIntegration[w_, kx_, ky_] := 
    (MyInterpolation[MyIntegration[f[#1, #2, "#1", "#2"] &, 2 Pi/3], 4, 10])[kx, ky]
```

with a change in my interpolation function:

```
MyInterpolation[function_, kLimit_, kSteps_] := MyInterpolation[function, kLimit, kSteps] =
    Interpolation[
         Flatten[Table[{{κx, κy}, function /. {"#1" -> κx, "#2" -> κy}},
             {κx, -kLimit, kLimit, 2 kLimit/kSteps}, {κy, -kLimit, kLimit, 2 kLimit/kSteps}],
         1]
    ]
```

This way, the parameters for `MyInterpolation` will always have to be called `"#1"` and `"#2"` **with quotes**. I don't like this "solution", because I will need to keep track of how I call my parameters inside all my functions, but since I won't nest things like these too deeply, I am okay with this. Out of curiousity, however, I won't (yet) mark this as a solution, because I would love to know a more elegant way to do it.